# Time Series data in Cloudant or MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cloudant, nosql

Meeting room booking project will require to continuously add data for different meeting rooms for different time slots of the day. I am trying to use Nosql DB (cloudant or Mongo) for this purpose but I am not getting how to structure the JSON data/document. Should  I have one document for each meeting room like below?

```
{
name:"room A",
bookings: [
  {start:"10:00 AM", end:"12:00 AM", user:"Ram Sen"},
  {start:"08:00 AM", end:"09:00 AM", user:"Sam Roy"},
  {start:"01:00 PM", end:"3:00 PM", user:"Jadu Dey"}
]
}
```

and so on?

Answer (score 0):

In mongoDB the size of one document is limited. Document stores are specialized on a huge amount of documents. So I think it would be better to create a document with all meeting rooms and one document for every booking.
You can relate to a meeting room inside of the booking document.

for example:

```
{
  _id: generated ID
  rooms: [
    {_id:"1", name:"room1"},
    {_id:"2", name:"room2"},
    {_id:"3", name:"room3"},
  ]
}

{
  _id: generated ID
  name: "meeting",
  room: "1",
  start: "10:00 AM",
  end: "12:00 AM",
  user: [
    {name: "ron"},
    {name: "john"}
  ]
}
```